# How to acces a dict with @ in key, in django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

i converted a XML file with the follwing line, to a dict, with xmltodict:

```
<drivers>
  <driver enable="True" guid="{8702bdfa-53b8-4a83-bd01-854293141f11}">
     <Name>Intel Net e1d65x64.inf 12.17.8.7</Name>
```

Then i passed the dict to a django template and want to access the guid.

In python i can access it with `dict["drivers"]["drivers"]["@guid"]`, since xmltodict, converted the guid key to @guid.

However, i cant use `{{item.drivers.drivers.@guid}}` in django templates.

How can i access the guid in templates?

Comment: Can't you create your own data dict in `get_context_data()` method and return it? It should fix the problem.

Comment: And the end i simply reworte the key in the dict, to the key i want.